# how can i get the current product id in the product edit page custom tab collection grid, magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created custom tab under product edit page and shows grid under the tab but I need to show grid collection based current production id,if get current product id it shows the grid reneder url how to achieve this?

Comment: did you get it resolved?

Comment: yes @abduljavid